# SSRS report with directional indicator - displaying multiple indicators per row

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, indicator

I have an SSRS report where I am using a directional indicator to show profit with an up/down arrow:

[image: ReportBuilderPreview]

This indicator is placed under a rectangle.

My problem is that in report builder the report is working fine (like in the above screenshot), but when I check it on the report server through a web browser the full set of indicators are shown for each row of the report:

[image: ProblemBehaviour]

What could be causing this behaviour and how can I resolve it?

Comment: In your screenshot it looks like the column with the directional arrows isn't quite lined up with the rest of the columns.  How are you defining the directional arrow column?  Is it any different than the other columns?  Can you provide a screenshot of the report definition before it is run so we can see the formatting?